# Turn off codegen for XCode CoreData model

Tags: xcode, core-data, code-generation

Making CoreData model in XCode with already declared classes by myself, compiler code generated duplicates for me. How get rid of that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable all automatic code generation by setting the "tools version" for the data model file to Xcode 7.3. This won't have any other effect on the model-- there are no changes to the file format.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

In the Data Model editor, change the Codegen option in the data model inspector on the right to "Manual/none":

[image]

Sadly, as far as I know, you will have to do this for every Entity separately: there is no overall override.

Comment: You can still select multiple (all) entities with multiselect (`Shift` + `mouse select`) and after that change `Codegen` option to `Manual/None`. Changes should then apply for all selected entities.

Comment: @RafałRębacz Thanks for the tip - I hadn’t thought of trying that.